# Convert properties file into excel

Tags: java, excel, netbeans

Im trying to convert a properties file into an excel but i dont know how.

It's look like this in netBeans but i can copy an entire column or all, only let me one for one (And there is a lot of data..)

[image]

Anyone knows how to convert this to a excel or at least copy an entire column?

EDIT1: I'm asking this question looking for a non-programming answer because i think netbeans can do anythink like converting this into an excel.  (My english is not the best, i hope you can understand what i'm trying to say.)

Answer (score 2):

You should read the file using something like that:

Read the file to a String usign Files.readAllbytes() and then split the content into a list of Strings:

Then you should apply some java project like apache POI here is a example using excel:

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Use JExcelpApi, http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Download Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.12/

Tutorial: http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Comment: I hoped there were a way to convert it without programing! Thought netBeans can do that. But well, i will convert this into an excel with this api, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the properties file as a csv file.
Just rename it from `[filename].properties` to `[filename].csv`

Then you can import the csv file in Excel by using the import function whitch can be found in the menu under `Data` -> `from text`.

After clicking on `from text` there should open a popup in which you can set the import options.

In the first step inside the popupwindow select separated an go to the next step.

Here you can choose what symbol is the separator of the csv file.
Just write `=` into `Separator`->`other` and press on `finish`.

You can also find a good documentation about how to import csv to excel here: https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel